# How can I edit a game level using jmonkeyengine?

Tags: level-design, jmonkeyengine

I liked the [quake level](https://jmonkeyengine.googlecode.com/files/quake3level.zip) that comes with jME3. But if I want to edit that level, make it bigger or so, what editor or programming can I use to edit the level? If I open the zip file it's a bunch of texture files that I don't know how to combine to a level. Was the level constructed using some editor like Blender or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create q3 levels with GTKRadiant.
GTKRadiant saves levels as .map which stores the geoemtry as planes in a CSG fashion.